# How to configure Ninject to work with ServiceStack.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

In trying to configure ServiceStack.net to use Ninject as its IOC, I am getting errors referring to various bindings not being defined. Primarily for ICache Client.

What specific bindings need to be created to use Ninject properly?

Currently have specified:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>().To<SessionFactory>();//Is this correct/needed?
```

**Note**

I have created an IContainerAdapter as per the ServiceStack documention to implement the use of Ninject.
(Found here:[ServiceStack IOC Docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container))

**Note 2**
My apphost configure method looks like this:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new BindingModule());
        container.Adapter = new NinjectContainerAdapter(kernel);
}
```

**Note 3**

I have registered the ICacheClient as follows:
    Bind().To();

And I am now getting an error pointing to IRequest

```
Error activating IRequestLogger\nNo matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable
```

**Container Adapter**

```
public class NinjectContainerAdapter : IContainerAdapter
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectContainerAdapter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this._kernel = kernel;
    }

    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        return this._kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return this._kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you injected your Container adapter with:

```
container.Adapter = new NinjectIocAdapter(kernel);
```

If so, try also make your AppHost class **internal** if you haven't done so. There should only be 1 instance of AppHost and some IOC's like to create their own instance, wiping out all the configuration from the first one.

The behavior you're getting sounds like Ninject is complaining about unresolved dependencies. Make sure you get Ninject to return null with Unresolved dependencies by using `kernal.TryGet<T>` in your Container Adapter, e.g:

```
public T TryResolve<T>()
{
    return this._kernel.TryGet<T>();
}
```

Comment: Yes please see my second note above. Also tried changing to internal with not success

Comment: Error Message: Error activating ICacheClient\nNo matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable

Comment: Have you registered an ICacheClient? note property injections use the TryResolve<T> interface which your adapter should return null for un found/unregistered dependencies. The error looks like a Ninject one. Otherwise you could explicitly register it with Bind<ICacheClient>().To<MemoryCacheClient>(); but returning null is better since it's expected behavior.

Comment: Thank your for the help...please see note 3 above

Comment: Could this be a result of creating two kernels? I am creating one in my Configure method and another one on App start(for the rest of my app)...How can I avoid this?

Comment: yeah why 2 kernels? you can get access to your AppHost instance via either AppHostBase.Instance or EndpointHost.AppHost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8411/discussion-between-stephen776-and-mythz)

Comment: Would you suggest just wiring up my Ninject in the Configure method? I ask this because I also need to wire it up for my MVC app functionality via :   DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));

Comment: Even doing the above in the Configure method, I still get the error looking for IRequestLogger

Comment: See https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/App_Start/AppHost.cs#L124 for an example of sharing an IOC with ServiceStack + MVC

Comment: Hi, did this ever get resolved? Im facing a similar problem now with Ninject and SS..

Comment: @mythz the link is dead now, would you care to show another example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own IContainerAdapter and then set Container.Adapter in your AppHost